# ms sql count of sql errors for every day in a month including those with "0"

Tags: count

Trying to get count of sql errors for every day in a month including those with "0".

Tried this:

DECLARE @StartDate DATE = '2023-05-01';
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = '2023-05-31';

WITH DateRange AS (
SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date])
FROM DateRange
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, [Date]) <= @EndDate
)
SELECT [Date], COUNT(*) AS [RowCount]
FROM DateRange

LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[Errors] ON CONVERT(DATE, [dbo].[Errors].DateTime) = [Date]

GROUP BY [Date]
ORDER BY [Date];

GOT THIS: However there were no errors in the database after 5/22:
How do I include that dates with no errors

Date            RowCount

2023-05-01  9

2023-05-02  23

2023-05-03  10

2023-05-04  20

2023-05-05  14

2023-05-06  20

2023-05-07  12

2023-05-08  20

2023-05-09  25

2023-05-10  26

2023-05-11  14

2023-05-12  27

2023-05-13  33

2023-05-14  23

2023-05-15  17

2023-05-16  23

2023-05-17  17

2023-05-18  1

2023-05-19  1

2023-05-20  2

2023-05-21  1

2023-05-22  2